# Can't write to named pipe

Tags: linux, bash, named-pipes

I'm trying to write to a named pipe, made with **mkfifo**. But when I run the command, (ex) `ls > myNamedPipe`, I can no longer enter commands into the bash. I can still write characters and that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A named pipe remains opened until you read it from some other place. This is to permit communication between different processes.

Try:

```
mkfifo fifo
echo "foo" > fifo
```

Then open another terminal  and type:

```
cat fifo
```

If you return to you first terminal, you'll notice that you can now enter other commands.

See also what happends with the reverse :

```
# terminal 1
cat fifo

# terminal 2
echo "foo" > fifo

# and now you can see "foo" on terminal 1
```

If you want you terminal not to "hang on" when trying to write something to the fifo, attach to the fifo a file descriptor :

```
mkfifo fifo
exec 3<> fifo
echo "foo" > fifo
echo "bar" > fifo
```

Comment: Thanks - this works great! Can you explain me why, though? I don't quite get how the `exec 3<> fifo` line fixes things..

Comment: Attaching the fifo to a file descriptor causes the shell to buffer data written to the fifo. Without it, any write to the fifo blocks until something reads what is written. With the file descriptor, "foo" and "bar" are buffered by the shell, and anything reading from that file descriptor can read them later.