# How to queue ffmpeg FIFO

Tags: ffmpeg, queue

we build a service similar to youtube. Also converting runs fine with ffmpeg using this script from another post here:

> [How do I set up an ffmpeg queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698006/how-do-i-set-up-an-ffmpeg-queue)

```
#!/bin/bash

pipe=/tmp/ffmpeg

trap "rm -f $pipe" EXIT

# creating the FIFO    
[[ -p $pipe ]] || mkfifo $pipe

while true; do
# can't just use "while read line" if we 
# want this script to continue running.
read line < $pipe

# now implementing a bit of security,
# feel free to improve it.
# we ensure that the command is a ffmpeg one.
[[ $line =~ ^ffmpeg ]] && bash <<< "$line"
done
```

This works pretty good when i send one by one to the named pipe. When i send more than one at same time the second one queues the terminal to the point the first one finished. if a try more than 2 the third one will not be transcoded.

So i tried to workaround with background sending to get the terminal free (just drop the echo command and close the ssh connection) but this doesn't work, then i played around with screen -X but also no luck. Maybe someone has a good idea to deal this.

What i wanna do is: Every uploaded video which is needed to transcode will send a echo to the named pipe. FIFO should match but not blocking the terminal. So i think i need something to really queue ffmpeg input.

kindest regards
Francois